# Java applet - saving an image in a png format

Tags: java, image, applet, png

I am creating a simple applet for avatar-making. You can choose face, hair, eyes, etc and then save it to a disc as a png file. The simple version (without the interface for the simplicity purpose) looks like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Example extends Applet
 {

 Image my_gif;
 Image my_gif2;
 URL base;
 MediaTracker mt;

 public void init() 
 {
        mt = new MediaTracker(this);
     try {
             base = getDocumentBase();
     }
     catch (Exception e) {}

       my_gif = getImage(base,"1.gif");
       my_gif2 = getImage(base,"2.gif");

       mt.addImage(my_gif,1);
       mt.addImage(my_gif2,2);

      try {
           mt.waitForAll();
      }
      catch (InterruptedException  e) {}
  }
 public void paint(Graphics g) 
 {
       g.drawImage(my_gif,0,0,this);
     g.drawImage(my_gif2,0,0,this);
 }
 }
```

This example consists of two files. When run they are visible in a correct way. Now I would like to save it to a disc - I can save one image using BufferedImage but I want to "flatten" two or more images and save it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I also agree that perhaps my approach is not the right one and would be grateful for any corrections.

Answer (score 2):

**Beware quickly written and untested code!**

The basic concept is this:
You load the images from which you combine the avatar, then you create a new empty image and draw each part of the avatar onto it. After that you just save the newly created image to a file.

Important note: The getPath() Method will fail for unsigned applets cause of a AccessViolation. I suppose a FileChooser would be a better approach here.

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Avatar {
    // Graphics
    private GraphicsConfiguration config = GraphicsEnvironment
            .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice()
            .getDefaultConfiguration();

    private BufferedImage faceImage;
    private BufferedImage hairImage;
    private BufferedImage mouthImage;

    public Avatar(final String face, final String hair, final String mouth,
            final String out) {

        // Load the Image parts
        faceImage = load(face);
        hairImage = load(hair);
        mouthImage = load(mouth);

        // Combine the images
        BufferedImage outImage = combine();

        // Save the new image
        try {
            ImageIO.write(outImage, "png", new File(getPath()
                    + "screenshot.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    // Combine
    private BufferedImage combine() {
        // Create an empty image
        BufferedImage buffer = create(200, 400, true);

        // Get the graphics context
        Graphics2D g = buffer.createGraphics();

        // Draw all 3 images onto the empty one
        g.drawImage(faceImage, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(hairImage, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(mouthImage, 0, 0, null);

        // Get rid of the graphics context
        g.dispose();
        return buffer;
    }

    // Image
    private URL getURL(final String filename) {
        URL url = Avatar.class.getResource(filename);
        return url;
    }

    private BufferedImage load(final String file) {
        URL filename = getURL(file);
        if (filename == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            try {
                return ImageIO.read(filename);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    private BufferedImage create(final int width, final int height,
            final boolean alpha) {
        BufferedImage buffer = config.createCompatibleImage(width, height,
                alpha ? Transparency.TRANSLUCENT : Transparency.OPAQUE);
        return buffer;
    }

    // Path
    private final String getPath() {
        String path = currentPath();
        if (currentPath().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jar")) {
            path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        }
        return path;

    }

    private String currentPath() {
        try {
            return this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
                    .getLocation().toURI().getPath();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the applet signed?  If saving the result is the only reason you need to run as a signed applet, you might be able to have the applet POST the image bytes[] to the server, and then redirect the browser to download the resulting PNG image.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that help u to edit images

```
Hope it helps you

/*Arpana*/

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ConvolveOp;
import java.awt.image.Kernel;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class ConvolveApp extends JFrame {
  CPanel displayPanel;

  JButton sharpenButton, blurringButton, edButton, resetButton;

  public ConvolveApp() {
    super();
    Container container = getContentPane();

    displayPanel = new CPanel();
    container.add(displayPanel);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    panel
        .setBorder(new TitledBorder(
            "Click a Button to Perform the Associated Operation and Reset..."));

    sharpenButton = new JButton("Sharpen");
    sharpenButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    blurringButton = new JButton("Blur");
    blurringButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    edButton = new JButton("Edge Detect");
    edButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
    resetButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    panel.add(sharpenButton);
    panel.add(blurringButton);
    panel.add(edButton);
    panel.add(resetButton);

    container.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });
     //setSize(100,100);
    setSize(displayPanel.getWidth()+50, displayPanel.getHeight() );
    setVisible(true); 
  }
  public static void main(String arg[]) {
    new ConvolveApp();
  }

  class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();

      if (button.equals(sharpenButton)) {
        displayPanel.sharpen();
        displayPanel.repaint();
      } else if (button.equals(blurringButton)) {
        displayPanel.blur();
        displayPanel.repaint();
      } else if (button.equals(edButton)) {
        displayPanel.edgeDetect();
        displayPanel.repaint();
      } else if (button.equals(resetButton)) {
        displayPanel.reset();
        displayPanel.repaint();
      }
    }
  }
}

class CPanel extends JLabel {
  Image displayImage;

  BufferedImage biSrc;

  BufferedImage biDest; // Destination image is mandetory.

  BufferedImage bi; // Only an additional reference.

  Graphics2D big;

  CPanel() {
    setBackground(Color.black);
    loadImage();
    setSize(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage.getWidth(this)); 
    createBufferedImages();
    bi = biSrc;
  }

  public void loadImage() {
    displayImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Desert.jpg");
    MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);
    mt.addImage(displayImage, 1);
    try {
      mt.waitForAll();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Exception while loading.");
    }
    if (displayImage.getWidth(this) == -1) {
      System.out.println("No jpg file");
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }

  public void createBufferedImages() {
    biSrc = new BufferedImage(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage
        .getHeight(this), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    big = biSrc.createGraphics();
    big.drawImage(displayImage, 0, 0, this);

    biDest = new BufferedImage(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage
        .getHeight(this), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  }

  public void sharpen() {
    float data[] = { -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 9.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f };
    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
    ConvolveOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,
        null);
    convolve.filter(biSrc, biDest);
    bi = biDest;
  }

  public void blur() {
    float data[] = { 0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.25f, 0.125f,
        0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.0625f };
    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
    ConvolveOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,
        null);
    convolve.filter(biSrc, biDest);
    bi = biDest;
  }

    public void edgeDetect() {
    float data[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f };

    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
    ConvolveOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,
        null);
    convolve.filter(biSrc, biDest);

    bi = biDest;
  }

  public void reset() {
    big.setColor(Color.black);
    big.clearRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(this), bi.getHeight(this));
    big.drawImage(displayImage, 0, 0, this);
    bi = biSrc;
  }

  public void update(Graphics g) {
    g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    paintComponent(g);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2D.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);
  }
}
```