# An applet to save a receiving RTP stream

Tags: stream, applet, save, rtp

I want to do something similar to this [Save an Image to a File in a Applet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200874/save-an-image-to-a-file-in-a-applet) .

But instead of just an image I want to save an RTP stream.

I am using the RTP Player code http://code.google.com/p/openmeetings/source/browse/trunk/webapp/src/screenviewer/RTPPlayerApplet.java?r=2353

Can this be done so that I could just add a command button to save stream and to stop saving the stream?

Comment: BTW - please do not forget to add a question mark (?) to questions.

Answer (score 0):

> CAn this be done so that I could just add a command button to save stream and to stop saving the stream.

Yes.  So long as the data is being sent back to the same server, the applet can be sand-boxed.

BTW - what is the source of the images?

---

I mis-read your question slightly.  I thought you were trying to transmit the images back to the server.  To save them to disk, why not follow the strategy I outlined in the linked thread?

To save your user the hassle of having to approve every single image sage, it would be better to compact all the images to a single file (e.g. Zip or MOV) that can hold all of them.

Comment: The FOS will enable me to save the video stream?